# How can I add web interface to an electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to build a desktop app using Electron.
I know that Electron handles both the server and the interface part and I am thinking to build the app in such a way that these two parts to be clearly delimited.

What I want to do in the future is to build a website, most likely using React and use the Electron app as a server.

Since Electron is based on NodeJs I don't see why this wouldn't be possible. I plan to expose some APIs and the web app to use them. So a part of the desktop app will be the server for the web app too.

My questions are:

How easy is it to achieve this?

And how does this approach stands in terms of security concerns?

Answer (score 1):

> How easy is it to achieve this?

Usually, pretty easy. All you need to do is create an electron file that starts your Node.js server on port X, opens a `BrowserWindow`, and instructs the `BrowserWindow` to load the server url: `http://127.0.0.1:X`.

However, a traditional web server usually has a different architecture from an Electron app backend. Web servers often connect to a central database containing data for all users, while an Electron backend only manages one user's data. This has a few implications:

- Where an Electron app backend may keep persistent data about its one user, a web app
  backend will probably keep a database of data about all of its users.
- If an Electron app doesn't keep persistent data but uses the filesystem to read and
  write files, a web app will probably have to implement virtual filesystems with a
  database, or else use a sandboxed filesystem with something like the 
  [Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem).
- If an Electron app does neither of the above, consider if your application even needs
  a backend. It may be possible to create a web app using only static files with something
  like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), which would probably be better off as a web
  page than an Electron app.

> And how does this approach stands in terms of security concerns?

It's possible to set up your server to listen on `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`. This means
your data flows solely through the device and not across the network, which prevents outsiders from intercepting it unless they have already compromised the device.